# How can I compute the integral $e^{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2\right)}$

Tags: density-function

Let (X, Y) be a pair of random variables with density

$$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y):=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{(\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2)}, (x,y)\in\mathbb R.$$

1. Give the marginal laws of X and Y and identify it with usual laws.
2. Are X and Y independent?

I am stuck from the first question. How can I compute the integral of $e^{(\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2)}$? The teacher gave us a hint: $xy-y^2=-(y-\frac{x}{2})^2+\frac{x^2}{4}$. But I still can't figure it out. Could anybody give me solutions?

Comment: Using the hint you can rewrite the exponential term as $\exp(f(x,y)) = \exp(g(x,y))\exp(h(x))$, so that now you should be able to perform the first integral in the double integral as $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(g(x,y)) dy$, give it a go!

Comment: For each fixed $y$, the integral in $x$ diverges to $+\infty$.  So perhaps you must have a misprint there?  Say a minus sign in the exponent is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have $-\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2$ in the exponential  so
$$
-\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2=-\frac{x^2}{2}-\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\frac{x^2}{4}=-\frac{x^2}{4}-(y-\frac{x}{2})^2
$$
and the joint density can be written as
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm e^{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2\right)}=
\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{2}}\mathrm e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}}_{X\sim\mathcal N(0,2)}\times\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1/2}}\mathrm e^{-\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}}_{{Y|X\sim\mathcal N(x/2,1/2)}}
$$
The exponential can also be written as
$$
-\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2=-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2
$$
and the joint density can be written as
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm e^{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+xy-y^2\right)}=
\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}}_{Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)}\times\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}}_{{X|Y\sim\mathcal N(y,1)}}
$$

Then integratin over $x$ we find
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm d x=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }\mathrm e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}\mathrm d x}_{=1}
$$
that is $Y\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.

$X$ and $Y$ anre not independent, because
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ne f_X(x)f_Y(y)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!